# SharePoint IF Function Close Survey Option

Tags: sharepoint, if-statement, sharepoint-2013, survey, iif-function

Hi I wondered if this query was within the remit of SharePoint Server 2013 or if someone can point out something quite obvious that i'm missing.

I wanted to create a Survey and offer different Questions based on the answers to those questions. I have tried building something similar in info path and it doesn't seem to meet my requirements and workflows on surveys are proving to be extremely frustrating.

Basically what I need is when someone answers "Yes" or "Maybe" to the first question it proceeds to the other questions and records the results in a viewable format (this works fine)

However when a person answers "No" to the same question I want it to end the survey saving the results (of how many people answered No) and offer some sort of message. I only administor the site collection and familiar with but not confident enough to play around with script

I thought Branching might be my solution but it only offers the option for another question. I had hope in an IF statement after looking at the required syntax but nothing seems to fit.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks